Sol swap funds missing on my phantom wallet. Coin from Raydium
I purchased 0.25 Sol of a meme coin called BITCOIN. The Transaction was marked as successful. The 0.25 Sol was taken from my original balance, but my wallet was never updated with the new meme coin. Basically, my money was taken, and I did not receive the coin. I would like to get my 0.25 Sol back please.
